# Reading requirements

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Do I have to read a book before I ask a question about it? Can I ask questions about books I haven't finished reading yet? Do I have to read a book several times before I ask a question about it?

Comment: By extension, do I have to read all the sequels before asking about a book? Even if that book is *Dune*? Do I have to read all letters of Tolkien before I ask a question about The Hobbit?

Comment: @b_jonas - no but you have to read Silmarillion.

Answer (score 23):

### **There shouldn't be any strict requirements about this.**

Some questions, such as [reading-order](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-order) questions, are best asked *before* someone has read the books. But even for plot explanation or literary analysis questions, it shouldn't be *necessary* to have read the book before asking questions about it.

If someone who hasn't read the book posts a question to which the answer should be obvious (say, "whom does Elizabeth Bennet marry in the end?" or "who's the main character in *1984*?"), then we can mark such questions as bad by downvoting them if necessary. But that doesn't mean we should require people to read the book before posting questions about it. **It's perfectly possible to post high-quality questions about something you haven't read.** (*Source: I do it all the time over on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), and have rarely if ever embarrassed myself by doing so.*)

Comment: I even got a Nice Question badge on a question that was based on a faulty premise, about something that I hadn't [watched](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113895/how-was-seven-of-nine-the-seventh-of-nine-people-to-be-assimilated).